# create app ShortCut on home screen when it installed and open last screen of it

Tags: java, android, shortcut

i am trying to create ShortCut when app installed . i am using following code

```
Intent shortcutintent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    shortcutintent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
    shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.iconname));
    Parcelable icon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.appicon);
    shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);
    shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashActivity.class));
    sendBroadcast(shortcutintent);enter code here
```

but in this it always open DashActivity . let say i am using app and app is in c Activity and its running in bacgkground  now when i click on shortcut it is opening DashActivity not the opening which where active ie c

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to listen for a shortcut request from the home screen-- with an intent filter like so in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".ShortCutActivity" android:label="@string/shortcut_label">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then in the activity that receives the intent, you create an intent for your shortcut and return it as the activity result.

```
// create shortcut if requested
ShortcutIconResource icon =
    Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.icon);

Intent intent = new Intent();

Intent launchIntent = new Intent(this,ActivityToLaunch.class);

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, launchIntent);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, someNickname());
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);

setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

it is opening DashActivity becoz in this line it is provided to open this.
 shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashActivity.class));

change the name of this Activity with your own Activity which u want to open.
hope this Helps.

Comment: i want it should open last act

Comment: get current activity by Following code.                                                                        **Activity  currentActivity = ((MyApp)context.getApplicationContext()).getCurrentActivity():**                           then pass this current activity instead of DashActivity.                                       Hope this Slove your problem

Answer (score 0):

From `shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashActivity.class));`
 remove the `DashActivity.class` and provide your applications launcher activity name...so that it will work as you expected.

Comment: DashActivity is launcher activity , android:launchMode="singleTask"

Comment: Remove the launch mode from the activity...It will works

Comment: but i cant other way ?

Comment: What you mean by "i cant other way ?"?

Comment: sorry i mean i cant remove mode as its using for different purpose . any alternative for this?